# Concept of creating static Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to create a Map object that can lose value only if we explicitly delete it from map.
I have created Map object like

```
public static Map<Long,String> listUser =new HasMap<Long,String>();
```

but every time class object is created new instance of Map is also created that contain null value. I want to create a Map instance that contain value we stored before.

Comment: This is a very difficult question to understand.  You should probably write a failing test that demonstrates the behavior you want but cannot figure out how to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing the default behavior of Maps, they remember entries. The problem I think you are having is that you probably need only one Map and not new instances. If you need a second map that has the contents of the first, look into "copy constructors" but your question as stated doesn't suggest that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

`static` here means that the object is created once for the whole life of the executing program (or server)

If you want to store it between program executions, you need [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're creating new versions of a variable that already exists. Just use the one that's created by the compiler. Here's a quick example:

```
class Example{
  public static Map<Long,String> listUser =new HashMap<Long,String>();
}

// other file
class Main{
  public static int main(String args[]){
    // Notice how I didn't have to do Example.listUser = new HashMap<etc> here
    Example.listUser.add(12, "Bob");
    Example.listUser.add(50, "George");
  }
}
```